# How to do this: example.com/users/user1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How to make a url to look like `example.com/users/user`?

I do not use a framework and I write procedural PHP code.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I have no experience with Apache rules

Comment: Keyword: mod_rewrite. And now go do some research please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need somthing like this? Not clear what is your requirement. Check this [blog](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/21-very-useful-htaccess-tips-tricks/) for more

> Rewriting example.com/user.php?username=xyz to example.com/xyz

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

Refer [htaccess2 tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)